# Retrieving 10 records from Oracle materialized view in Entity Framework VERY slow

Tags: asp.net-mvc, oracle, entity-framework

I am building an ASP.NET MVC 5 application to get read-only access to a few records at a time (Roughly between 2 and 12 rows). The records are stored in Oracle 11, and accessed via Entity Framework 6, from a large un-keyed materialized view in Oracle.  I have tried List, IQueryable, and IEnumerable to grab these records. (Example below)

```
public List<FACT> GetCollisionList(string collisionMRN)
{
    var collisions = from c in _context.FACT
                     where c.COLLISION_RECORD_NUMBER.Equals 
                    (DbFunctions.AsNonUnicode(collisionMRN),
                     StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)
                         select c;

    return collisions.ToList();
}
```

It is taking roughly 20 seconds with each to return the records. My questions are: A. What is likely the best of these three methods? (List, IQueryable, IEnumerable) ------ B. Is the un-keyed materialized view a fundamental problem? (I do have a model in the .NET data repository, that only uses 8 of the 100+ columns that the view contains) .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can try as below on your query.

**Note :** use AsNoTracking() and remove the lazy loading.

**AsNoTracking() :**

> Returns a new query where the entities returned will not be cached in
>   the DbContext

```
public List<FACT> GetCollisionList(string collisionMRN)
{

_context.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;//to remove lazy loading

 var collisions = (from c in _context.FACT
                     where c.COLLISION_RECORD_NUMBER.Equals 
                    (DbFunctions.AsNonUnicode(collisionMRN),
                     StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)
                         select c).AsNoTracking();

return collisions.ToList();

}
```

You can read this doc for learning more options about query optimisation : [**Performance Considerations for EF**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/hh949853.aspx)

Comment: any feedback for this ?

Comment: These are good answers! I'm still finding out what options I have to changing the Oracle side.

Comment: Thanks guys! Very helpful answers here. Sampath and Kacper were both very helpful with this issue.

Answer (score 0):

If the view has no primary key nor index on columns used in your where clause this is in fact problem. If no index Oracle needs to do full scan of the MV. So you should consider indexing the MV.

If those 100 columns can contain a lot of data which may cause some delay on pulling data you should consider creating view over your MV that selects only those columns you need and query the view. But this probably won't help much (unless columns are BLOBs or CLOBs or other huge types). The main problem seem to be no index.

You should generate execution plan for your query and check method of accessing MV and estimated cost of the query.